# How to encrypt and decrypt xml using openSSL with public key

Tags: linux, openssl

Can any one able to tell me how to encrypt and decrypt a xml file using openssl. I can able to create privatekey using the Linux command

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024
```

And got my private key as `private.pem`. Created public key using

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

got my public key as `public.pem`

Now what I want is I want to encrypt the XML file using this public key and again want to decrypt using my private key.

Comment: What happened to the return key on your keyboard? Did it leave because it didn't feel needed? :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public.pem -pubin -in file.xml -out file.xml.encrypted
```

Hint: I cheated and looked here:

http://www.devco.net/archives/2006/02/13/public_-_private_key_encryption_using_openssl.php